# "Save and copy changes to all stack exchange communities" doesn't update my network profile

Tags: support, profile-page, stack-exchange

I assumed it would, but it doesn't.

It updates the profiles on all the other various SE sites I've joined, just not SE itself.

Is it not supposed to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The network profile doesn't sync with community-specific profiles automatically and can be updated manually with information pulled from any of yours community-specific profiles (at your choice).

Let's assume you'd like to put any information on your network profile; here're your steps:

**1. Update your community specific or community-global profile first**

To update a community-specific profile or all the profiles at once, [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current).

> [image: 1, 2, 3, go!]

After you make the necessary changes, you have two options at the bottom of the page: whether you want to copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities you're registered or will register later, or to keep the changes only for the current community:

> [image: What will you pick?]

**2. Sync your network profile with any community you've just updated**

Navigate to your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/current) and select, where you would like to derive information from:

[image]

*Optional step 3*: revert changes to a specific community you've just updated, thus leaving unique information on the network profile, since it does not sync by itself (I can't think of useful scenario why one would do it, but anyway)

Answer (score 4):

This *used* to be automatic, but no more. You now need to [manually update your network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254566/dont-force-sync-with-my-oldest-account-on-my-network-profile) if you want to see it reflect your profile on a given site:

> Note that this is a one time copy, not an ongoing sync. If you want to update your profile on stackexchange.com after making changes on your Q&A site of choice, you'll need to repeat this process.

The process is:

- Go to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current).
- Click on the *Update profile info* link below the blue profile description box on the right
- Pick a site from the dropdown and click *Copy*.

Comment: Hmm, I guess the push from SO or another site to the SE profile would interfere with your ability to choose which site your SE profile updated from. It makes sense in a way, but I just figured if you clicked that button, they'd all be the same anyway. It's not a big deal, I was just curious.

Comment: When I do this, it pulls over the profile summary text but it doesn't change what appears under my network profile name and location. Right now, it just shows my LinkedIn URL and nothing else (even though I've added my Github and Twitter, too). How do you update what information appears under your name and location?

Comment: @SergeiWallace the network profile doesn’t support GitHub and Twitter links, so they won’t be copied. Your network profile has your name, and your location, description and link fields. You used your link field for your LinkedIn URL.