# How can you edit what appears under your name and location on your Stack Overflow network profile?

Tags: bug, profile-page, meta, network-profile

How do you edit what information appears under name and location on your Stack Overflow network profile?

I was able to successfully update the About Me section on my network profile using the "Update Profile Info". However, that doesn't appear to affect what information shows directly under your name and location.

Right now, my network profile just displays my LinkedIn URL (which I believe may be an old version of my *About Me* text), but it doesn't include other URLs I've added on my profile more recently such as Twitter and GitHub. If it is my old *About Me* text, then why doesn't it update, as well? Seems like a potential bug.

See screenshot below:

[image: Sergei Wallace - Stack Overflow Network Profile with unchangeable URL text highlighted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [comment on a similar post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357210/save-and-copy-changes-to-all-stack-exchange-communities-doesnt-update-my-netw/357214?noredirect=1#comment855182_357214) by [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters):

> The network profile doesn’t support GitHub and Twitter links, so they won’t be copied. Your network profile has your name, and your location, description and link fields. You used your link field for your LinkedIn URL.

Answer (score 5):

#### How do you edit what information appears under name and location on your Stack Overflow network profile?

Click on the "Update profile link" on the right side.

You will get a dialog that allows you to "Choose a site to copy profile information from". Pick the site that has the links you want to appear in you network profile.

Comment: I did that but it didn't update what displayed under the name and location. Just that blue box to the right.